# How to change control visibility of Orbeon forms at runtime?

Tags: javascript, runtime, orbeon

I am trying to find out how to change the control visibility of a text box at runtime for an Orbeon form. At the following sample, I have created an image button - when the user clicks on this button I wish to show / hide another button but unfortunately my code is not working properly:

```
<xf:trigger> 
                            <xf:label>
                                <xf:output value="concat('&lt;img src=''http://**********:8081/green-light.png', image, '''&gt;')"
                                           mediatype="text/html"/>
                            </xf:label> 
                            <xxf:script event="DOMActivate">
                              var remarksControl = ORBEON.jQuery('*[id $= "remarks-control"]')[0];
                                remarksControl.hidden= true;
                            </xxf:script>  
                        </xf:trigger> 

                        </fr:c>
                    <fr:c y="1" x="7" w="6">

                    </fr:c>
                    <fr:c x="1" y="2" w="6">
                        <xf:input id="remarks-control" bind="remarks-bind">
                            <xf:label ref="$form-resources/remarks/label"/>
                            <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/remarks/hint"/>
                            <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>                                                                                                                                              
                        </xf:input>
                    </fr:c>
```

What is the best approach to implement this kind of functionality? What I am actually trying to achieve is to have a form with several images and the user when clicks on an image she will be able to activate / deactivate several text fields on the form.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi George, am I right to assume that you are using the images as a way for users to choose one of several choices? I.e. you could also use radio buttons for that purpose? ‑Alex

Comment: Hi Alex, actually what I want to achieve is to hide/show several fields on a form when the user clicks on a button. The initial form includes a set of required fields and I need to add an icon next to some of these fields so that when the user clicks on the icon, a group of additional fields is displayed below the initial field in order to be filled-in. Although we managed to implement it using 'Yes/No Answer' control, I had a request to replace the 'Yes/No Answer' control with an image button - if possible. How could I use a button (trigger) in order to change the visibility of the  controls?

Comment: Got it George, I've posted the method I'd recommend in an answer below. You'll let me know if this works for you! ‑Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to avoid using JavaScript to handle a case like this. The button is bound to an element, just like any other control. So you write some XForms that stores a value, say `show-textfield`, when the button is clicked. Assuming your button is named `button`, you can do so with the following [custom model](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/advanced/custom):

```
<xf:model xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">

    <xf:action
        observer="button-control"
        event="DOMActivate">
        <xf:setvalue ref="event('xxf:binding')">show-textfield</xf:setvalue>
    </xf:action>

</xf:model>
```

Then the control you want to show upon the button being clicked can have the Visibility formula `$button = 'show-textfield'`. As a result, you'll get a result like:

[image: Clicking on the button shows the textfield]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is really what I was looking for! Just a question - Is there available any user guide or manual explaining all these advanced issues for XForms? I really wish to delve into these details but the available documentation is mainly for developers that have a clear picture of the Orbeon forms architecture and provided functionality.

Comment: Hi George, ideally, everything you'd want to do should be doable directly in Form Builder ;). What you want to do here is coming to Form Builder, but it's true that writing your own code, in this case using XForms, will always add a whole new level of possibilities. Since XForms is a standard, you can browse through the [spec](https://www.w3.org/community/xformsusers/wiki/XForms_2.0), and if you can't find what you're looking for, feel free to post a question on Stack Overflow, and we'll be happy to help. ‑Alex